# Sort a list of objects by an attribute given a string of the name of the attribute

Tags: python

So far:

```
def sort_by(column):
    for order in sorted(orders, key=lambda order: order.column):
        ...

list('ratio')
```

Clearly both `ratio` and `'ratio'` are illegal arguments here. I think Django and most other python web frameworks do something like this internally. Is there a pattern for this?

Comment: You just clobbered the built-in `list` fuction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(..., key=operator.attrgetter(column))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def arrange_list(column):
    for order in sorted(orders, key=lambda order: order.__dict__[column]):
        ...
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It is better to use `getattr(order, column)` than to use `__dict__`. Not all objects have a `__dict__`, e.g. classes which use `__slots__`, or namedtuples.